# Docker: What is the simplest way to secure a private registry?

Tags: authentication, docker

Our Docker images ship closed sources, we need to store them somewhere safe, using own private docker registry.
We search **the simplest way to deploy a private docker registry with a simple authentication layer**.

I found :

- this manual way http://www.activestate.com/blog/2014/01/deploying-your-own-private-docker-registry
- and the `shipyard/docker-private-registry` docker image based on stackbrew/registry and adding basic auth via Nginx - https://github.com/shipyard/docker-private-registry

I think use `shipyard/docker-private-registry`, but **is there one another best way?**

Comment: Another howto : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-docker-registry-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Just jumping in, ProGet now supports private Docker registers, quick how to tutorial here: http://inedo.com/support/tutorials/proget/getting-started-with-proget-private-docker-registries

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm still learning how to run and use Docker, consider this an idea:

```
# Run the registry on the server, allow only localhost connection
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:5000:5000 registry

# On the client, setup ssh tunneling
ssh -N -L 5000:localhost:5000 user@server
```

The registry is then accessible at localhost:5000, authentication is done through ssh that you probably already know and use.

Sources:

- https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/docker-registry-run-private-docker-image-repository/
- https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/

Comment: Where can I read more about this? I want my registry to be available for some of our users, so I'm planning to run the registry on the EC2 instance with public ip address. I thought of some kind of auth proxy similar to one described here: http://engineering.opendns.com/2014/09/03/docker-private-registry-authentication/ - in this case I could just put all ports except proxy's 443 behind firewall and guarantee security. In case of ssh tunnel, do I need to keep running ssh server on 22 port?

Comment: Does it mean that if `user` has access to ssh tunnel, the same `user` can do a normal ssh connection to my server and open terminal?

Comment: The solution I gave is the simplest way to setup an authentication layer for a docker container.

Comment: Any ssh documentation online should let you know more about tunnelling, ssh is mature and well covered online.

You'll always need an ssh server to tunnel through ssh, restrictions should be configurable (http://askubuntu.com/questions/48129/how-to-create-a-restricted-ssh-user-for-port-forwarding)

It's really the simplest way to setup an authentication layer for a docker container. If you need complex restrictions rules, go for something more specific (nginx auth described here for example: http://www.activestate.com/blog/2014/01/deploying-your-own-private-docker-registry).

Answer (score 14):

You can also use an Nginx front-end with a Basic Auth and an SSL certificate.

Regarding the SSL certificate I have tried couple of hours to have a working self-signed certificate but Docker wasn't able to work with the registry. To solve this I have a free signed certificate which work perfectly. (I have used StartSSL but there are others).
Also be careful when generating the certificate. If you want to have the registry running at the URL registry.damienroch.com, you must give this URL with the sub-domain otherwise it's not going to work.

You can perform all this setup using Docker and my nginx-proxy image (See the README on Github: https://github.com/zedtux/nginx-proxy).
This means that in the case you have installed nginx using the distribution package manager, you will replace it by a containerised nginx.

1. Place your certificate (`.crt` and `.key` files) on your server in a folder (I'm using `/etc/docker/nginx/ssl/` and the certificate names are `private-registry.crt` and `private-registry.key`)
2. Generate a .htpasswd file and upload it on your server (I'm using `/etc/docker/nginx/htpasswd/` and the filename is `accounts.htpasswd`)
3. Create a folder where the images will be stored (I'm using `/etc/docker/registry/`)
4. Using docker run my nginx-proxy image
5. Run the docker registry with some environment variable that nginx-proxy will use to configure itself.

Here is an example of the commands to run for the previous steps:

```
sudo docker run -d --name nginx -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -v /etc/docker/nginx/ssl/:/etc/nginx/ssl/ -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock -v /etc/docker/nginx/htpasswd/:/etc/nginx/htpasswd/ zedtux/nginx-proxy:latest
sudo docker run -d --name registry -e VIRTUAL_HOST=registry.damienroch.com -e MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE=0 -e SSL_FILENAME=private-registry -e HTPASSWD_FILENAME=accounts -e DOCKER_REGISTRY=true -v /etc/docker/registry/data/:/tmp/registry registry
```

The first line starts nginx and the second one the registry. It's important to do it in this order.

When both are up and running you should be able to login with:

```
docker login https://registry.damienroch.com
```

Comment: /etc/ is a bad idea to store images. You should rather try to use something in /var like /var/lib/docker/images!

Comment: For anyone reading this answer, the [original repo](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) from which this was forked now supports basic authentication and per-host Nginx configurations.

Answer (score 1):

I have create *an almost ready to use but certainly ready to function* setup for running a docker-registry: https://github.com/kwk/docker-registry-setup .

Maybe it helps.

Everything (**Registry**, **Auth server**, and **LDAP server**) is running in containers which makes parts replacable as soon as you're ready to. The setup is fully configured to make it easy to get started. There're even demo certificates for HTTPs but they should be replaced at some point.

If you don't want LDAP authentication but simple static authentication you can disable it in `auth/config/config.yml` and put in your own combination of usernames and hashed passwords.