# Docker Hub Login Without Password

Tags: docker, dockerhub

So, I'm trying to figure something out, and I haven't seen anything so far.

I setup a docker hub account, and I want to push to a private repo from a CI server, and pull from it on boxes in production.

As far as I can see, though, the only way to do this is to go to every machine and put in my password, the same one I use for web login.

That can't be right, is it?
Is there something I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the configuration file that has the authentication to the production boxes. It should be in ~/.dockercfg.

Comment: Seems like the .dockercfg contains my username and password, just base64 encoded. So, someone else can't stumble upon it, but every machine still very much has my plaintext password.

Comment: Yes, but your question was how to connect machines to hub without having to interactively add the password, not how to do it securely. If you want to avoid leaving you password in every machine you could use a private docker registry that mirrors you docker hub registry. In that way only have one machine that can communicate with docker hub so you can keep the config file private more easily.

Comment: I suppose I meant my question to both be about how to get access, and distribute it. I can see your point though.

Answer (score 0):

**private registry** doesn't have built-in authentication, most solutions people use is **nginx**.

[How To Set Up a Private Docker Registry on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-docker-registry-on-ubuntu-14-04)

[What is the simplest way to secure a private registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990784/docker-what-is-the-simplest-way-to-secure-a-private-registry)