# How to set password to a docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have created a docker container and its accessible to everyone in the network. So is there any way so that i can set any authentication for a particular container. As i am new to this technology. plz help me. Thanks in advance.

I checked man page and it shows as login as a option. Do it will help me in this situation.

Comment: You need to set up a proper private registry and include authentication. This is far too broad and arguably out of scope for this site. Look into [Portus](http://port.us.org).

Answer (score 0):

There is already answer for similar question which can cover yours. Take a look [Docker: What is the simplest way to secure a private registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990784/docker-what-is-the-simplest-way-to-secure-a-private-registry).

In short:

```
# Run the registry on the server, allow only localhost connection
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:5000:5000 registry

# On the client, setup ssh tunneling
ssh -N -L 5000:localhost:5000 user@server
```